# What are the popular 'web-ready' functional programming languages?

Tags: functional-programming

This is a simple question: what are the most popular/used/developed (libraries a plus) functional programming languages that are ready to be used for web development?  I don't mind if they're pure languages or not, but I would prefer to exclude such languages as Ruby and Python.  I am thinking along the lines of **F#** or **Scheme** (and those these aren't pure functional programming languages, I don't mind, I'm simply looking for a language that can work with types fluently).

Since asking this question the main languages that have been recommended are **Haskell**, **Lisp**, and **Scheme**.

Thanks.

**Edits:** 
-Checked out [state of web development using functional programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230046/state-of-web-development-using-functional-programming-language) which seems to favor a **Lisp**.
-How-to for web programming with Lisp or Scheme: [How I Can do web programming with Lisp or Scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275547/how-i-can-do-web-programming-with-lisp-or-scheme/1275667#1275667)

Comment: Yes, make this a wiki or it's going to get closed real fast.

Comment: And I would hardly call Scheme a purely functional language. Scheme is a dialect of Lisp, by the way.

Comment: While Scheme is multi-paradigm, its main focus is being functional.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are the few I could remember top of my head:

- [Lift](http://liftweb.net/) for Scala
- [Play](http://www.playframework.org/) for Scala
- [HappStack](http://happstack.com/index.html) for Haskell
- [Compojure](http://github.com/blog/308-compojure-clojure-web-framework) for Clojure

Comment: +1 for Lift, it's already in commercial use.  See here: http://www.softwaresecretweapons.com/jspwiki/twitter-linkedin-to-migrate-to-scala-should-you

Answer (score 8):

OCaml has a web framework, [Ocsigen](http://ocsigen.org/)

The language also comes with some nifty utilities that makes easy to build simple web applications, like [netplex](http://docs.camlcity.org/docs/godilib/3.11/netplex) module (I've used it before in a school project, an [mvc framework](http://code.google.com/p/flarearrow/), it did almost all the web/socket part)

Answer (score 3):

I have not used it myself, but [WebSharper](http://www.intellifactory.com/products/wsp/Home.aspx) looks interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Haskell has a plethora of web frameworks.  The most well-established framework is [Happs](http://happs.org/), but there are several new and active projects:

- [Yesod](http://docs.yesodweb.com/#)
- [Snap](http://snapframework.com/)
- [Haskell on a horse](http://haskell.on-a-horse.org/)

The [full list is on the Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Applications_and_libraries/Web_programming).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at Erlang's Webmachine, MochiWeb (includes a bunch of libraries), Nitrogen, etc.

http://bitbucket.org/justin/webmachine/wiki/Home

http://github.com/mochi/mochiweb

http://nitrogenproject.com/

Answer (score 1):

PLT Racket has a webserver use.

I believe mod_lisp makes any Lisp available for web use.

Also, [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253340/what-is-the-ecosystem-for-haskell-web-development) talks about using Haskell as a web language.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is partly in jest, but some people try their best to do functional programming in JavaScript:

http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/
[Javascript as a functional language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145053/javascript-as-a-functional-language)

Using the same language on client and server has to count as a plus, even if the language isn't purely functional.